# Does the constant $C$ in this solution to a differential equation equal infinity?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, infinity, substitution, constants

The problem is $y' = -\frac{1}{t^2} - \frac{1}{t}y + y^2;\ y_p = \frac{1}{t}$.  My solution is

$$\begin{align}
y = \frac{1}{t} + B &\implies y' = -\frac{1}{t^2} + B' \\
&\implies -\frac{1}{t^2} - \frac{1}{t}y + y^2 = -\frac{1}{t^2} + B' \\
&\implies -\frac{1}{t^2} - \frac{1}{t} \left(\frac{1}{t} + B \right) + \left(\frac{1}{t} + B\right)^2 = -\frac{1}{t^2} + B' \\
&\implies B' - \frac{1}{t}B = B^2 \\
&\implies L = B^{-1} \\
&\implies L' = -B^{-2} \left(B^2 + \frac{1}{t}B \right) \\
&\implies L' + \frac{1}{tB} = -1 \\
&\implies L' + \frac{1}{t}L = -1 \\
&\implies L_h = \frac{1}{t} \\
&\implies L = \frac{1}{t}\int\frac{-1}{\frac{1}{t}}dt \\
&\implies L = \frac{1}{t} \left(-\frac{1}{2}t^2 + C_{tentative} \right) \\
&\implies L = \frac{C - t^2}{2t} \\
&\implies B = \frac{2t}{C - t^2} \\
&\implies y = \frac{1}{t} + \frac{2t}{C - t^2}
\end{align}$$

Although this solution does not appear equivalent to the answer given in my book, one or two people in chat reviewed this work and could not see anything incorrect.  The issue is that the given particular solution, $y_p = \frac{1}{t}$, cannot be obtained by plugging any finite value into the $C$ in my general solution.  We *could* say that the general solution yields the given particular solution when $C =$ infinity, more specifically, when $C =$ some $\aleph$ expression which makes the term $\frac{2t}{C - t^2}$ disappear regardless of $t$, but this feels a bit outside the box for a textbook problem.  Is my general solution correct, and if so, how if at all can we derive the given particular solution from it?

Comment: Your solution is not the "general solution" in the sense that it produces all possible solutions.  In your deduction, when you made $L=B^{-1}$, you implicitly excluded $B=0$. That is why you can not obtain $y_p$ from your "general" solution.

Comment: Is there a way to test the B = 0 case, as there is when dividing an algebraic equation by a variable?

Comment: The most general form would be to consider $C= a/b$, then we get: 
$$ y = \frac{1}{t} + \frac{2bt}{a - bt^2} $$
which covers the solution $y_p$ (set $b=0$ and $a \neq 0$) and also the solution $ y = -\frac{1}{t}$ (set $a=0$ and $b\neq 0$), and, of course, all the other solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very common situation.  A general solution for a nonlinear $n$-th order differential equation is a solution depending on $n$ independent parameters, but it does not necessarily give you all the solutions.  As in this case, some may be obtained as limits where some parameters go to $\infty$.  There are also cases where some particular solutions (singular solutions) are obtained as envelopes of the general solution.

Comment: Does the general solution always give the "main" families of solutions?  For example, having graphed a general solution on Desmos with a slider representing each integration constant, letting one slider play at a time produces a smoothly transitioning animated sequence of curves.  Is this reliable as a means of seeing all particular solutions except outliers, or can there be entire animated sequences not captured by the general solution?

Answer (score 1):

For non-linear equations like this, it is valid to take $C\to\infty$. You can also write $c = \frac{1}{C}$ to get an alternate form

$$ y(t) = \frac{1}{t} + \frac{2ct}{1-ct^2} $$

Comment: Would we actually have to think of $C$ as some sort of $\aleph$, an actual infinite quantity larger than any real number, rather than a finite real approaching $\infty$?  If we use the usual calculus notion of approaching infinity, it seems we could always find a $|t|$ large enough relative to $C$ that the term doesn't disappear.